# Reading/Writing files in Python and using Dictionary for WordCount list

Tags: python

i'm doing a python exercise that has to open and read the text file of Alice In Wonderland, populate a dictionary by making a wordcount, and then writing out that file. For the love of me, it won't work. Any tips??

```
f = open('/Users/yongcho822/Desktop/alice.txt', 'r')

count = {}

for line in f:
    for word in line.split():

        # remove punctuation
        word = word.replace('_', '').replace('"', '').replace(',', '').replace('.', '')
        word = word.replace('-', '').replace('?', '').replace('!', '').replace("'", "")
        word = word.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(':', '').replace('[', '')
        word = word.replace(']', '').replace(';', '')

        # ignore case
        word = word.lower()

        # ignore numbers
        if word.isalpha():
            if word in count:
                count[word] = count[word] + 1
            else:
                count[word] = 1

keys = list(count.keys())
keys.sort()

# save the word count analysis to a file
out = open('/Users/yongcho822/Desktop/alice.txt', 'w')

for word in keys:
    out.write(word + " " + str(count[word]))
    out.write('\n')

print("The word 'alice' appears " + str(count['alice']) + " times in the book.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain you want to be *writing* to a file called `alice.txt`, when that is also the name of your input file?

Check your input file (`Desktop/alice.txt`) to make sure you didn't accidentally overwrite it! Use a different name, e.g. `output.txt` for your output file.

<strike>The other minor issue is the indentation of your second `for` loop, but I think that's just formatting of your question.</strike>

Otherwise, your code worked for me. I found 167 x `Alice`, in the text I used.

Comment: gah it works now that I wrote it to something else like output.txt! is there a reason why it would've looped funny and given all word counts as 0 when i had the read and write files under the same name? Thanks so much @Symmitchry!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

You should be using the `with` context manager to open your files. That will ensure that a file that is opened is automatically closed before being somehow reopened. You can also simply call `f.close()` to ensure nothing weird happens.

The reason was likely some crazy issue with not doing `seek(0)` to rewind the file pointer after you read to the end of it, before starting to write to it again. Always use `with open(fname, 'w') as f:` context manager: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to have gotten rid of the punctuation would have been to do as follows,

```
word=word.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```